# Conditional URL/routing symfony2: clean URLs

Tags: symfony

Any chance we can do this in Symfony:

- If there **isn't** a **page** attribute: go to `/category/{category}`
- If there **is** a **page** attribute: go to `/category/{category}/page/{page}`

I would need to add `/page/{page}` only if there is a page attribute.

---

*So far, I only managed to have this:*

- If there **isn't** a **page** attribute: go to `/category/{category}`
- If there **is** a **page** attribute: go to `/category/{category}/{page}`

With the following:

```xml
<route id="category_view" pattern="/category/{categoryId}/page/{page}">
    <default key="_controller">AcmeHouseBundle:House:view</default>
    <default key="categoryId">null</default>
    <default key="page">1</default>
    <requirement key="categoryId">\d+</requirement>
    <requirement key="page">\d+</requirement>
</route>
```

---

The difference is in having `/category/{category}/page/{page}` instead of `/category/{category}/{page}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now there is no support for such things (until [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/7051) is merged). So you can achieve this only by having two different routes:

```xml
<route id="category_view" pattern="/category/{categoryId}">
    <default key="_controller">AcmeHouseBundle:House:view</default>
    <default key="categoryId">null</default>
    <default key="page">1</default>
    <requirement key="categoryId">\d+</requirement>
</route>

<route id="category_view_page" pattern="/category/{categoryId}/page/{page}">
    <default key="_controller">AcmeHouseBundle:House:view</default>
    <default key="categoryId">null</default>
    <default key="page">1</default>
    <requirement key="categoryId">\d+</requirement>
    <requirement key="page">\d+</requirement>
</route>
```

Comment: Glad to help. And thanks for the help with syntax highlighting :)